# mysql report multiple values on same line

Tags: unix, mysql, sql, query

I have a bunch of temperature sensors in my house.  I poll the sensors every minute and store the data in a mysql database that looks like this:

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| property   | varchar(50)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| devloc     | varchar(50)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| sensortype | varchar(50)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| timest     | datetime     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| value      | decimal(8,4) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

For any given polling cycle, I sample 17 sensors, each one with a unique "devloc".  The timestamp given to a particular sample is the same for all 17 entries.  A given sample run can be reported like this:

```
mysql> select * from sample where date(timest) = curdate() and 
       property='myhouse' order by timest desc limit 17;
+-----------+---------------------+------------+---------------------+---------+
| property  | devloc              | sensortype | timest              | value   |
+-----------+---------------------+------------+---------------------+---------+
| myhouse   | garage_ext1         | temp       | 2021-01-29 00:19:01 | 34.4750 |
| myhouse   | hvac_attic_supply   | temp       | 2021-01-29 00:19:01 | 73.5125 |
| myhouse   | hvac_attic_return   | temp       | 2021-01-29 00:19:01 | 70.9250 |
| myhouse   | hvac_main_supply    | temp       | 2021-01-29 00:19:01 | 79.7000 |
| myhouse   | hvac_main_return    | temp       | 2021-01-29 00:19:01 | 66.6500 |
| myhouse   | attic_side          | temp       | 2021-01-29 00:19:01 | 69.8000 |
| myhouse   | attic_main          | temp       | 2021-01-29 00:19:01 | 69.2375 |
| myhouse   | upstairs_right_bed  | temp       | 2021-01-29 00:19:01 | 76.5500 |
| myhouse   | upstairs_middle_bed | temp       | 2021-01-29 00:19:01 | 70.3625 |
| myhouse   | upstairs_guest_bed  | temp       | 2021-01-29 00:19:01 | 72.6125 |
| myhouse   | garage_main         | temp       | 2021-01-29 00:19:01 | 54.9500 |
| myhouse   | basement            | temp       | 2021-01-29 00:19:01 | 63.6125 |
| myhouse   | study               | temp       | 2021-01-29 00:19:01 | 71.1500 |
| myhouse   | master_bed          | temp       | 2021-01-29 00:19:01 | 69.4625 |
| myhouse   | kitchen             | temp       | 2021-01-29 00:19:01 | 69.3500 |
| myhouse   | den                 | temp       | 2021-01-29 00:19:01 | 69.6875 |
| myhouse   | outside             | temp       | 2021-01-29 00:17:52 | 24.3500 |
+-----------+---------------------+------------+---------------------+---------+
```

I would like to report on 3 specific devloc values for a given date (or date range).  I want to see outside, hvac_main_return and hvac_main_supply on a single line, for each sample interval.  Something like this:

```
+---------------------+---------+------------------+------------------+----------+
| timest              | outside | hvac_main_return | hvac_main_supply | property |
+---------------------+---------+------------------+------------------+----------+
| 2021-01-29 00:19:01 | 24.3500 | 66.6500          | 79.7000          | myhouse  |
| 2021-01-29 00:20:01 | 24.1000 | 71.5200          | 87.6125          | myhouse  |
... etc ... etc...
+---------------------+---------+------------------+------------------+----------+
```

I can write simple queries, but this one is out of my league.  I have limited database/SQL knowledge.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think I found my answer at (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8283541/merging-multiple-rows-into-one-row-and-multiple-columns-on-mysql).

A little modification and I came up with this:

```
select x.timest,     
    max(case when x.devloc='outside' then x.value end) as outside,     
    max(case when x.devloc='hvac_main_return' then x.value end) as hvac_main_return,     
    max(case when x.devloc='hvac_main_supply' then x.value end) as hvac_main_supply     
from sample x where date(timest) = curdate() 
group by timest     
order by timest desc;
```

It gives me output like this:

```
+---------------------+---------+------------------+------------------+
| timest              | outside | hvac_main_return | hvac_main_supply |
+---------------------+---------+------------------+------------------+
| 2021-01-28 23:59:54 | 24.8000 |          67.4375 |          82.9625 |
| 2021-01-28 23:58:45 | 24.9125 |          67.1000 |          80.8250 |
| 2021-01-28 23:57:42 | 24.9125 |          66.0875 |          78.2375 |
| 2021-01-28 23:56:33 | 24.9125 |          64.9625 |          74.8625 |
| 2021-01-28 23:55:32 | 25.0250 |          62.3750 |          73.0625 |
| 2021-01-28 23:54:17 | 25.0250 |          62.8250 |          74.7500 |
+---------------------+---------+------------------+------------------+
```

And I can tweak the **where date(timest) = curdate()** to give me a specific date or date range.

Does anyone know how I can add the difference between hvac_main_return and hvac_main_supply as another column?